# updates to documents in mongoengine using positional operator updates only first element in the array

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql, mongoengine

I'm using mongoengine and I have a collection `Question`.

```
class Question(Document):
    id = StringField(primary_key=True)
    answers = EmbeddedDocumentListField(Answer)

class Answer(EmbeddedDocument):
    id = StringField(primary_key=True)
    uid = StringField()
    answer = EmbeddedDocumentField(UserAnswer)

class UserAnswer(EmbeddedDocument):
    status = StringField()
```

Query to update a Answer document in answers field.

```
Question.objects(id="question_id", answers__uid="uid").update(set__answers__S__answer__status="new_status")
```

The above query updates only the first matching document in the `answers` list.

How can I make it update all matching document in the list?

**UPDATE**:  I tried running the query directly on the mongo shell, it also returned the same result. Is it that because my query is wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure about the mongoengine syntax but there is one option in MongoDB update query which you can pass as  {multi:true}. This will update multiple documents which are matching with your query part.

Comment: Yes.  mongoengine has [update_one](http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#mongoengine.queryset.QuerySet.update_one) for single document update and [update](http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#mongoengine.queryset.QuerySet.update) for multi document update.

Comment: I executed this query `db.question.updateOne({_id:"questionId","answers.uid": "uid",answers.answer.status": "old_status"}, {$set:{"answers.$.answer.status": "new_status"}})` on the shell. I expected this to update the answer status of user `uid`having status `old_status` but it instead updated the first document in array even though it wasn't the matching document.

Answer (score 0):

There is no support for it yet in mongoengine but you can achieve it by using **raw** on `update`, see this thread: https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/issues/2019#issuecomment-473706068

**UPDATE**
You have to use the [filtered positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/#up._S_[%3Cidentifier%3E]). 
In a mongo shell (requires mongo >=3.6), I manage to get it working with

```
c = db.question
c.update({}, {$set: {'answers.$[i].answer.status': 'new_status'}}, {multi: true, arrayFilters: [ {'i.answer.status': 'old_status'} ]})
```

You can access the pymongo collection with `Question._get_collection()`, the pymongo syntax is:

```
c.update_many({}, {'$set': {'answers.$[i].answer.status': 'new_status'}}, array_filters=[{'i.answer.status': 'old_status'}])
```

Comment: Thanks. I tries using `__raw__` but still the same result. also i noticed something with the query. I'll update in the question.